# In neovim, how can I share registers between editor instances?

Tags: neovim, register, clientserver

I know that vim had the client/server divide that allowed register sharing between different vim clients, but how do you achieve the same thing in neovim? It doesn't support the client/server flags. I saw [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5348/how-can-i-use-servername-and-remote-in-neovim), but my goal is specifically sharing registers, not imitating the rest of client/server. Is something like [neovim remote](https://github.com/mhinz/neovim-remote) the only way, or is there something simpler I can do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LEI is right; and the `neovim` help instructions give this as a [specific use case](https://neovim.io/doc/user/starting.html#shada-read-write) for that feature:

> Two commands can be used to read and write the ShaDa file manually. 
>   This can be used to exchange registers between two running Vim
>   programs: First type ":wsh" in one and then ":rsh" in the other.

Answer (score 7):

No idea about the clientserver feature, the simplest way I can think of would be to use the [system clipboard](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/96/12003) by default when yanking or pasting which can be done with:

```
set clipboard=unnamedplus
```

Depending on your OS and environment, you might need other tweaks for it to work seamlessly.

---

Also, you may be able to leverage the `viminfo` file (or `:h shada` on neovim):

> The ShaDa file is used to store:
>
> - The command line history.
> - The search string history.
> - The input-line history.
> - **Contents of non-empty registers.**
> - Marks for several files.
> - File marks, pointing to locations in files.
> - Last search/substitute pattern (for 'n' and '&').
> - The buffer list.
> - Global variables.

Answer (score 1):

use tmux，tmux buffer to unname register, uname register to tmux buffer

https://github.com/tracyone/t-vim/blob/master/autoload/te/tmux.vim

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, because I dont know anymore where I found this:

```
" share data between nvim instances (registers etc)
augroup SHADA
    autocmd!
    autocmd CursorHold,TextYankPost,FocusGained,FocusLost *
                \ if exists(':rshada') | rshada | wshada | endif
augroup END
```