# Open file in new buffer within original vim instance from a terminal buffer

Tags: neovim, terminal-buffer

The terminal emulator is handy!

However, using it to open a file you wish to edit (while remaining in vim) is troublesome because simply doing `vim myfile.txt` will spawn a 'vim within vim inception' type situation.

Is there a way to short-circuit this behavior so as to open a given file in a new buffer of the existing vim instance?

A nice side effect to potential solution is that it would effectively give you an alternate way to navigate to and open files (ie-  alternative to a vim specific tree or file browser plugin)

Comment: Ups! I just now saw that you tagged it with `neovim`. Not sure if this would work there. I might have to delete it / move it somewhere more suited.

Comment: No worries!  I appreciate the detailed advice and your approach there looks solid.   Even in vanilla vim I see however the solution is not necessarily a quick one-liner so I may take some time on the weekend to experiment with your help there.  Thanks again.

Comment: I have no experience with neovim and use the original Vim only on Windows, where the `+clientserver` feature is always enabled. There in a terminal inside Vim the environment variable VIM_SERVERNAME is defined, so with `vim --servername %VIM_SERVERNAME% --remote myfile.txt` I was able to open myfile.txt in the original Vim instance (both console and GUI).

Comment: @JürgenKrämer Indeed. I tried that at first, but had issues with switching windows. Testing now I am not able to reproduce, - so not sure what it was. If it works even 95% of the time it would be a lot more simple

Comment: Would the following answer help you [how can I use servername and remote in neovim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5348/how-can-i-use-servername-and-remote-in-neovim)

Answer (score 3):

*Sorry, I did not see the [neovim](/questions/tagged/neovim) tag before I wrote and posted. This is for Vim and I have to figure out what to do with it. Delete / move / …. My bad. No idea if this would work in neovim.*

---

One could use the `:h clientserver`.

*Tried this first but had some issues where it did not switch window before opening resulting it opening in the terminal window. Tested again after comment by Mr. Krämer and not able to reproduce, so likely a very rare glitch.*

Example:

```
vim --servername "$VIM_SERVERNAME" --remote-send '<C-w><C-w>' --remote a*
```

Simply add it as an alias or the like:

```
alias svim="vim --servername \"\$VIM_SERVERNAME\" \
      --remote-send '<C-w><C-w>' --remote"
svim foo b*
```

It requires the Vim session to be run as server. If not one can become by

`:call remote_startserver('foo')`

---

Another option <strike>that is easier to get smooth</strike>  is the `:h terminal-api`. (Considering edit above, perhaps not :)

It gives the possibility to send commands back to Vim.

Besides the already supported `drop` one can also call functions. The function name has to start with `Tapi_` and the terminal started with `++api=Tapi_function_name`.

On the shell / terminal side one can then print a special sequence to send data to the Vim instance that opened it.

`<Esc>]51;` + `data` + `<07>`

The `data` is JSON and for terminal API calls using `call` it has the format:

`["call", "Tapi_function_name", DATA]` where DATA can be anything from a number, string, to an JSON array or object.

Modified another script I used to test for this.

### Basics

Send a reply in the format:

```json
{
        "split": 0,
        "stay" : 1,
        "files": ["file_A", "file_B", "file_C"]
}
```

- `split`: always split (0 = false, 1 = true)
- `stay` : stay in terminal (0 = false, 1 = true)

#### On the Vim side:

```vim
fun! Tapi_File_open(term_bufnr, args)
        " Escape the file-names and create a string "
        " we can use with for example :next"
        let files = join(map(a:args['files'], 'fnameescape(v:val)'), ' ')
        " Window ID's "
        let win_term = win_getid(winnr())
        let win_use = win_getid(winnr('#'))

        if win_use == 0 || win_term == win_use || a:args['split']
                split
        else
                call win_gotoid(win_use)
        endif
        exe ":next " . files
        if a:args['stay']
                call win_gotoid(win_term)
        endif
endfun

" Custom command to open a terminal with the API enabled."
command! FileTerm :terminal ++api=Tapi_File_open
```

### On the Terminal side

One could use Vim in Ex mode to generate the data. Something like:

```vim
let TAPI_FUNCTION = 'Tapi_Files_open'
let f = map(argv(), '"\"".fnameescape(fnamemodify(v:val, ":p"))."\""')
let reply = [
        \ "call",
        \ TAPI_FUNCTION,
        \ #{
                \ files: f,
                \ split: 0,
                \ goto: 0
        \}
\ ]
exe "set t_ts=\<Esc>]51; t_fs=\x07"
let &titlestring = json_encode(reply)
redraw
qa
```

Instead of using `titlestring` it would likely  be better to use a temporary file that one sourced after. That way one can use `-s` as well.

And call it by some alias or small script that in turn sources it:

`vim -E -c "source argv2json_cmd.vim" -- file1 file2 file3 ...`

---

#### Using bash

This is a crude`bash` script. The `help` section should be explanatory.

```
./svim --vvv -g *.txt
```

---

## NB! NB!

**=============**

StackExchange destroys tabs in code. In bash script below there are required TAB's in the `print_help()` section. To copy the script click <kbd>[edit](https://vi.stackexchange.com/posts/37820/edit)</kbd> on this answer and copy the text from the raw text.

---

```bash
#! /bin/bash -

stay=1
split=0
eopt=0
verbose=0
v_files=()

print_help() {
    cat<<-EOH >&2
    USAGE: $0 [OPTIONS] <FILES>

      Open file(s) from terminal in Vim where
      terminal has been started with:
        ++api=Tapi_File_open

    OPTIONS
      -h --help   This help
      -n --stay   Stay in terminal window
      -g --goto   Goto opened document(s)
      -s --split  Split
         --vv     Print information in terminal
         --vvv    Print information + JSON arg
         --       End of options
    EOH
}

for arg in "$@"; do
        # Options section
        if [ $eopt -eq 0 ] && [ "${arg:0:1}" = "-" ]; then
                case "$arg" in
                -h|--help) print_help; exit ;;
                -n|--stay) stay=1 ;;
                -g|--goto) stay=0 ;;
                -s|--split) split=1 ;;
                --vv) verbose=1 ;;
                --vvv) verbose=2 ;;
                --) eopt=1 ;;
                esac
        else
                # Escape backslash then double quote
                v_files+=( "$(printf %s "$(realpath -- "$arg")" | \
                        sed 's/\\/\\\\/g;s/"/\\"/g')" )
        fi
done
# Join file-names into string
files=$(printf '"%s",' "${v_files[@]}")
# Verbose
if [ $verbose -gt 0 ]; then
        printf '\033[1;34mOpen files in vim (stay: %d, split: %d)\033[0m\n' \
                "$stay" "$split" >&2
fi
# Extra verbose: print JSON data
if [ $verbose -gt 1 ]; then
        printf '\n\033[0;36m{"stay": %d, "split": %d, "files": [%s]}\033[0m\n\n' \
                "$stay" "$split" "$files" >&2
fi

# Call Vim by printing special sequence
printf '\033]51;['\
'"call", "Tapi_File_open",'\
'{"stay": %d, "split": %d, "files": [%s]}'\
']\007' \
"$stay" "$split" "$files"
```